# Enhanced WordPress Search

Tags: php, search, sql

I have been trying various ways and means to create a user form that would allow people to search a WordPress site using the following fields:

```
All of these words: < input field >
The exact phrase: < input field >
Any of these words: < input field >
None of these words: < input field >
```

However I am just not getting it to work - is this even possible within the WordPress scenario?

I had thought I could somehow manipulate the "s" parameter and pass in operators like plus, minus and double quotes but that doesn't seem to work.

Every plugin or page that I find on WordPress search show various ways and means of targeting categories or tags and so on but none for actually handling the "s" parameter itself

Is this possible actually or I am just going down the wrong path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is somehow possible as you can phrase SQL queries to match your conditions but it will not perform very well as the MySQL table structure is not designed for this kind of full-text search.

However, the solution requires more than just passing the search query (the user input) to the default WordPress `s` query variable. You'll have to adapt the complete SQL query manually.

First, let's have a look on the concrete MySQL clauses for each of your condition. In the examples I assume, that the user's search query is `lorem ipsum dolor`.

**All of these words**

```
WHERE 1=1 AND
    `post_content` LIKE "%lorem%"
AND 
    `post_content` LIKE "%ipsum%"
AND 
    `post_content` LIKE "%dolor%"
```

The example shows just the `WHERE` clause and only compares against the `post_content` field. As we want the result to match *all three* words, we look for every word solely and combine each comparison with an `AND`. `%` is a wildcard character that says MySQL that there might be other characters or not.

**The exact phrase**

```
WHERE 1=1 AND
    `post_content` LIKE "%lorem ipsum dolor%"
```

In this case we match for the exact phrase.

**Any of these words**

```
WHERE 1=1 AND
    `post_content` LIKE "%lorem%"
OR 
    `post_content` LIKE "%ipsum%"
OR
    `post_content` LIKE "%dolor%"
```

This one looks pretty similar to the first example except that we replaced the `AND` with an `OR` as we want to *one or more* of all these words.

**None of these words**

```
WHERE 1=1 AND
    `post_content` NOT LIKE "%lorem%"
AND 
    `post_content` NOT LIKE "%ipsum%"
AND
    `post_content` NOT LIKE "%dolor%"
```

Finally we reverse the logic and searching for entries that does *not match each* of the words in the search query.

### Filter the WordPress query

The important filter to alter the `WHERE` clause in the WordPress DB query is called [`posts_where`](https://github.com/johnpbloch/wordpress/blob/4.5.3/wp-includes/query.php#L3184).

To affect only the main query I would start on `pre_get_posts` to assign the callback to `posts_where`:

```
<?php

add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( WP_Query $main_query ) {
        // Don't filter custom queries
        if ( ! $main_query->is_main_query() )
            return;

        // Validate the request if it comes from your search form
        if ( ! wpse235391_is_custom_search() ) {
            return;
        }

        add_filter(
            'posts_where',
            function( $where, WP_Query $query ) use ( $main_query ) {
                // Don't filter other queries than our main query
                if ( $query !== $main_query ) {
                    return $where;
                }

                // Validate and sanitize your search query here
                // Don't forget to use esc_sql() on each term!
                $search_query = trim( $_GET[ 'search_input' ] );
                $search_words = explode( ' ', $search_query );
                // remove empty words
                $search_words = array_filter(
                    $search_words,
                    function( $value ) {
                        return $value !== '';
                    }
                );
                array_map( 'esc_sql', $search_words );

                // Build the WHERE clause according to your request

                return $where;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Please note, that this code is just an example that should describe the general process. I would not suggest to use this code in production as it is not testable. The usage of anonymous functions is just a way to reduce the code to the essential part. Also it is not tested by myself and might need some further improvements to increase the interoperability. E.g. the conditional tag `is_search()` will return `FALSE` in this case.

### One word about scalability

These queries will be expensive in comparison to the default WordPress queries. That mean they will run slow if you have a large data pool and they will stress your MySQL server if you're expecting high traffic on your search (e.g. using that search for a auto suggest UI). That is nothing that can completely be «optimized away», we're just reaching the limits of MySQL. The better way to go in these cases is to use a optimized search index like [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).